# Removing results based on condition on SQL

Tags: sql, multiple-conditions

Dataset context: Table has a column `SEX_CODE` that can be M, F, B (married, so the name is the combination of two names). So a `household_ID` can have three duplicates, all with different `SEX_CODE`'s, and categorized in 3 separate `sub_id`. (There's also 'U'-unknown, but those never have duplicate `household_ID` so we can leave them out)

Goal: I'll need to deal with the following conditions:

1. If a `household_ID` has a duplicate with `SEX_CODE`='M' and 'F' return both of those rows.
2. If a `household_ID` has a duplicate with `SEX_CODE`='B' and 'F'/'M'
   then return only 'F'/'M' (or remove 'B').
3. If a `household_ID` has a duplicate with `SEX_CODE`='B' and 'F' and 'M'
   then return only 'F' and 'M' (or remove 'B').

There are several issues I'm running into

1. My main query is grouping by `household_ID` and `sub_ID`, so I can't get 2 rows to spit out if those rows have the same `household_ID` and `sub_ID`.
2. I don't know how to split off into 3 cases. I can split off by two cases with the use of `CASE` and `COUNT`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1009f/1)

I feel like I need to approach it in an entirely different way other than by group, but I don't know how to group by cases.

I can manually delete them in Excel (highlight duplicates>filter by color>filter sex_code 'B'>delete 'em all) but the query is going to be like 60,000+ rows so I was wondering if it was possible to do in `SQL`. But if this isn't possible don't worry about it and I'll just do it in Excel.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, nothing in your database is called `person_id` and that seems rather central to your description of the problem.

Comment: Is `person_ID` actually supposed to be `household_ID` or vice versa?

Comment: Yeah person_id is household_id. My bad. Made changes to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions - ID == person_ID == household_ID (given that ID is present in the fiddle, and neither person_ID nor household_ID are).

```
SELECT id,id_sub,SEX
FROM household hh
WHERE SEX <> 'B'
    OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM household h where h.id=hh.id and ( h.SEX='F' or h.SEX='M') )
ORDER BY id
```

The query simply takes all records and for those that have SEX 'B' it checks if there is not a record in the table that has SEX 'F' or 'M' with the same ID.
It should be noted that records with value 'U' (not mentioned in OP), that is copied across without further ado.

If you wish to delete the records from the table with SEX 'B' where another SEX exists (F/M) - that would be very similar:

```
DELETE FROM household hh
WHERE SEX = 'B'
 AND
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM household h where h.id=hh.id and ( h.SEX='F' or h.SEX='M') )
```

With the obvious reversal of the conditions.

Comment: Thanks Koen. My bad for missing out 'U' and the mix-up of IDs. Made some changes to clarify question but forgot to check the whole post. Great use of WHERE clause with SELECT logic though. I'll test it out.